# Wrapall works with number but doesn't work with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Consider this code:

```
<script>
var n = 5; // NOTICE THIS LINE!!
$(function() {
var $newDiv = $("#content > .post:gt(5)").wrapAll($("<div>").addClass("hidden"));
$("<div>", { class: "onclick" }).insertBefore($newDiv.parent()).html("Load More");
$(".onclick").click(function() {
n = n+n+5; // NOTICE THIS LINE !!
$(this).remove();
$(".hidden .post").unwrap();
$newDiv = $("#content > .post:gt(n)").wrapAll($("<div>").addClass("hidden")); // NOTICE!!
$("<div>", { class: "onclick" }).insertBefore($newDiv.parent()).html("Load More");
});
});
</script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>

<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
</div>
<div class="onclick">CLICK ME!</div>
```

This works perfect **IF** I remove the "n" from "wrapAll" and enter numbers like 6 or 10. Why?

Please help!

Comment: You should read some basic tuto on how concatenate variable in string... So: `$("#content > .post:gt("+n+")")`

Answer (score 2):

It's because the code

```
$newDiv = $("#content > .post:gt(n)").wrapAll($("<div>").addClass("hidden"));
```

is assumed to be just a string ".post:gt(n)". It doesn't know it's a number.
Change this line to:

```
$newDiv = $("#content > .post:gt(" + n + ")").wrapAll($("<div>").addClass("hidden"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate variable in string:

```
$("#content > .post:gt(" + n + ")")
```